# uglifyjs-webpack-plugin how to disable mangle builtns without disable mangle properties

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

I'm using webpack to pack my project. I want to mangle properties too.

My dependencies:

```
"uglify-js": "^3.3.12",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
"webpack": "^4.0.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
```

My webpack.config.js

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const path = require('path');
    const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        mode: 'production',
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new UglifyJSPlugin({
                    uglifyOptions: {
                        mangle: {
                            properties: {
                                keep_quoted: true,
                                builtins: false // this option not working
                            },
                        },
                    },
                }),
            ],
        }
    };
```

Where did I get wrong?

an example: `console.log(window.navigator)` becomes `console.m(window.p)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new UglifyJSPlugin({
    uglifyOptions: {
        mangle: false
    }
})
```